# output a message to a user in the same html page using jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, message

I want to  output a message to the user in the same html page that confirms the date they have selected. I don't want an alert box, just to display it in the same page that they are in.

Thought it might be something like this, but I'm not sure:

```
document.writeln("You have selected: " + dateText);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('body').append("You have selected: " + dateText);
```

You can replace the "body" selector with any other elements you want

If the element has an id you do "#id_element" if it's a class ".class_element'

To learn more on selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Thanks. And I figured out I needed to parse it like this:  var dates = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', dateText);
        $('.info').append('You have selected:' + '<br />').append(dates.toString());

Comment: sure. you can even do the append in only one line of code if it's easier to you, you don't need to do it twice ;)

Comment: thanks, I changed it to one. but I've been finding either way that the string outputs every time I select a date. It doesn't replace the previous string just continues to append. any idea why?

Comment: yes of course because the append just... append :) if you want to replace your content you should use html(); instead like this $('.info').html('new content');

Comment: Thanks again. This is sort of related. The returned string delivers the timeStamp, although I have it set to false. Is there  a way to set it to false in the returned string?

Comment: Sorry i don't get this one :) May be ask another question for it. Don't forget to accept mine as well please ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of ways to do this. Here is one:

```
$(".message").text("You have selected: " + dateText);

<div class='message'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use these plugins if you are doing notifications:

http://needim.github.com/noty/

http://www.red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/cool-notification-messages-with-css3-and-jquery-demo.html#

I use them all the time. Saves me a lot of hustle. Idk, just saying :)